# Full Calendar and CodeIgniter send Start and End date

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, fullcalendar

I'm trying to get records by ajax request. I manage to get all the records from the table but now I want to send start and end date to controller to get only records from that interval.

What I have so far :

Script:

```
 events: {
    url: 'http://localhost/cms/calendar/get_calendar_ajax',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: true,
},
```

Controller:

```
public function get_calendar_ajax() {
    $response = json_encode($this->Calendar_model->getRecords() );

    echo $response;
}
```

Model:

```
public function getRecords()    {
    $data = $this->db->select()
                     ->from('fullcalendar')
                     ->get()->result();
    return $data;
}
```

I have tried :

Controller :

```
$response = json_encode($this->Calendar_model->getRecords($_GET['start'], $_GET['end']) );
```

Model :

```
public function getRecords($start, $end)    {
    $data = $this->db->select()
                     ->from('fullcalendar')
                     ->where('start >=', $start)
                     ->where('end <=', $end)
                     ->get()->result();
    return $data;
}
```

but with no luck ..

Comment: Check for the parameters on console you can see start and end parameter.

Comment: @Franky I did that ... the problems is sending then to the controller ...

Comment: Oh! i see.The dates are un-formated, format them first and pass records like this `public function getRecords(start, end){}` in your model and apply where condition

Comment: @Franky I have modified the question ... that is added to the model .. the problem is I don't no how to send start, end ... getRecords($_GET['start'], $_GET['end']) ... is not working ...

Comment: try formating them according to your database fields

Comment: @Franky they are .. console -> Params : start:"2015-03-30" end end:"2015-05-04"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74401/discussion-between-franky-and-george).

Comment: Sorry for afk... i mange to fix the problem .. it was only 1 small modification ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to find the error:

from:

```
type: 'POST',
```

change to

```
type: 'GET',
```